# Upon setting state, how to output the current state instead of the previous one? (class component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

This is my App.js component, the other component (Square.js) only handles html/jsx output. My first thought is that I need to use componentDidUpdate or something to that effect but I am neither entirely sure, nor entirely proficient in class components.

What I am attempting to achieve is to calculate and output the time in milliseconds between the moment a user clicks on a div and the another.

```
import Square from './Square';
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        gate: false,
        baseTime: null,
        time: null,
        oldTime: null,
        newTime: null,
        left: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), 
        top: Math.floor(Math.random() * 700)
      }

      this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      this.respawn = this.respawn.bind(this);
      this.time = this.time.bind(this);
    }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({newTime: new Date().getTime()})
    //this.setState({time: new Date().getTime()})
    this.setState({gate: !this.state.gate});
  }

  time() {
    var diff = this.state.newTime - this.state.oldTime;

        this.setState({oldTime: this.state.newTime});
        this.setState({time: Math.abs(diff), function () {console.log(diff)}});
      
        this.setState({newTime: new Date().getTime()});
        
    console.log(diff);
        //this.setState({time: new Date().getTime()})
}

componentDidUpdate(prevState){
  console.log(prevState.newTime);
}

respawn() {
    const rndTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * 900);
    const rndLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);

    this.setState({
        left: rndLeft,
        top: rndTop
    });

    this.time();
}

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Start</button>
        {this.state.gate && <Square 
        baseTime={this.state.baseTime} 
        respawn={this.respawn} 
        onClick={this.respawn} 
        left={this.state.left} 
        top={this.state.top}
        time={this.state.time}>
          </Square>}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `setState` accepts a callback that is guaranteed to be run after the state update ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate))

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what I need to pass for a callback function in order to get the correct output.

Comment: I see your calling time() from the respan() function. Is respan being called at all? Is that in the Square component? Maybe show us all your code

Comment: Use `componentDidUpdate` and access `this.state`, which will be the current state after an update.